# Time to first success of an event-intersection

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, random-variables

I beg your pardon for this (likely) silly question.

An urn contains $c$ elements of three different types, say $\alpha>0$ elements of type $A$, $\beta>0$ elements of type $B$ and $\gamma>0$ elements of type $G$.

We define the event $L_n^{AB}$ as to get, in $n$ independent trials (i.e. with replacement), at least one element of kind $A$ and at least one element of kind $B$, so that $P(L_n^{AB})=1-\left(\frac{\alpha+\gamma}{c}\right)^n-\left(\frac{\beta+\gamma}{c}\right)^n+\left(\frac{\gamma}{c}\right)^n$.

Clearly, the event $L_n^{AB}$ can occur at each trial, except the first one.

Following the suggestion of the (clever & kind) user Youem, I got the definition

> If you have an event $A$, and a number of trials $N$ (which can be $\infty$), then the definition of the "time to first success" of A is $$T_A = \min \{n \le N\;:\; A\;\text{is true at the $n-$th trial}\}$$

But I don't understand how to apply it in the case of the event $L_n^{AB}$.

Many thanks for your help!

My (partial and wobbly) solution is: $T_{L_n^{AB}}=2$ with probability $\frac{2\alpha\beta}{c^2}$ and $T_{L_n^{AB}}>2$ with probability $1-\frac{2\alpha\beta}{c^2}>0$, but it is not really a satisfactory answer.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to do.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Micheal (and sorry for late reply, but in the meanwhile I had to bring a little bird attacked by a cat to the veterinary!). My aim is to evaluate the expected time (or number of trials) to obtain the first success of the event $L_n^{AB}$.

Comment: Do you know about discrete time Markov chains?  For example related notes are in: http://ee.usc.edu/stochastic-nets/docs/markov-chains-travel-times.pdf

Comment: Unfortunately, not, Micheal. I am really not an expert of the field. Can you briefly explain how to attack the problem with Markov chains?

Comment: You can see the linked notes.  Also it may help to specify if the urn samples with replacement, or without.  Your example calculation suggests it samples with replacement.

Comment: Yes, with "independent trials" I actually meant "with replacement", I added it to the question. And thanks for the notes!

Comment: It looks like you have states $\{start, A, B, end\}$.

Comment: I added my attempt to solve the problem. It may at least help to understand what I am looking for!

Comment: Is Fig 2 in those notes not exactly the structure of your 4-state problem? Except your problem is simpler since all transitions take 1 time unit.

Comment: I must first study the notes. Then I will come back to you. Did you see my partial solution (I have just added it at the end of the question)? What is your view about it?

Comment: My view is that you are good at computing probabilities but it would help to think of what information is needed in this problem. The “state” is the relevant information about the past that impacts the future.  If you want to know “how much more time will I wait, on average?” someone would ask you “Well, what have you seen so far?”  For example, given that you have already seen A but not yet B, it should be easy to calculate the expected remaining time.

Comment: You are definitely right, Micheal. I have to think the whole problem in terms of information. Many thanks, also for the notes.